# Correct QueryPerformanceCounter Function implementation / Time changes everytime

Tags: c++, windows

I have to create a sorting algorithm function that returns number of comparisons, number of copies and number of MICROSECONDS it uses to finish its sorting.

I have seen that to use microseconds i have to use the function QueryPerformance counter as it's accurate (Ps i know it isn't portable between OS)

So i've done that :

```
void Exchange_sort(int vect[], int dim, int &countconf, int &countcopy, double &time)  
{

    LARGE_INTEGER a, b, oh, freq;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq); 
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&a);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&b);
    oh.QuadPart = b.QuadPart - a.QuadPart; //Saves in oh the overhead time (?) accuracy
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&a); 

    int i=0,j=0; // The sorting algorithm starts

    for (i=0 ; i<dim-1 ; i++)
    {   for(j=i+1 ; j<dim; j++ )
        {
            countconf++; // +1 Comparisons
            if (vect[i]>vect[j])
            {
                scambio ( vect[i],vect[j] );  // It is a function that swaps 2 integers
                countcopy=countcopy+3;  // +3 copies
            }
        }
    }

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&b); // Ends timer
    time = (  ( (double)(b.QuadPart - a.QuadPart - oh.QuadPart)  /freq.QuadPart )            
    *1000000 ) ;

}
```

The *1000000 is actually to give microseconds...

I think like this it should work but everytime i call the function giving it the same dimension of the array, it returns a different time... How can i solve that?

Thank you very much, and sorry for my bad coding

Comment: _'Ps i know it isn't portable between OS'_ Then add a tag for the correct one plase!! Also there's no need to be ashamed of bad coding here, the point is to ask correct questions and give the necessary informations to solve them.

Comment: Would you mind giving some of the "different time"s you are experiencing and what kind of results you expect?

Comment: And of course, some idea what your input is? (Always the same, randomized on each call, an idea of the number of elements, etc)

Comment: 10 elements, array of already sorted integers, last 3 times :

0.76991 -

1.15487 -

1.53982

Comment: @SuperN So, you are complaining that your measurements varies by *a single microsecond*?

Comment: @SuperN: What you are doing is pointless. Almost all of your time is spent measuring the time! And your efforts in trying to calculate and account for the overhead are laudable, but fruitless (I think.)

Comment: First of all i'm not complaining. I was UNSURE whether this is correct or not...How am i supposed to know that it isn't giving me random times? This is the first time i use such a function and what it was giving me sounded strange...

Comment: @SuperN: What happens if you comment-out the actual sorting part (so only the timing code remains)? What results do you get then? Does that give you an exact zero all the time?

Comment: @yzt: 0.000000 Yes it does

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the performance counter frequency *might* not be that great. It's usually several hundred thousand or more, which gives a microsecond or tens of microseconds resolution, but you should be aware that it can be even worse.

Secondly, if your array size is small, your sort might finish in nanoseconds or microseconds, and you would not be able to measure that accurately with `QueryPerformanceCounter`.

Thirdly, when your benchmark process is running, Windows might take the CPU away from it for a (relatively) long time, milliseconds or maybe even hundreds of milliseconds. This will lead to highly irregular and seemingly erratic timings.

I have two suggestions that you might pursue independently of each other:

1. I suggest you investigate using the `RDTSC` instruction (using inline assembly or compiler intrinsics or even an existing library.) Which will most likely give you better resolution with far less overhead. But I have to warn you that it has its own bag of problems.
2. For this type of benchmark, you have to run your sort routine with the exact same input many times (tens or hundreds) and then *take the smallest time measurement*. The reason that you should adopt this strategy is that there are a few phenomena that will interfere with your timing and make it *longer*, but there is nothing that can make your sort go faster than it would on paper. Therefore, you need to run the test many many times and hope to all your gods that the fastest time you've measured is the actual running time with no interference or noise.

**UPDATE**: Reading through the comments on the question, it seems that you are trying to time a very short-running piece of code with a timer that doesn't have enough resolution. Either increase your input size, or use RDTSC.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer for your question is that it **is not possible** to measure exactly the same time for all calls of the same function.

The fact that you are receiving different times is **expected** because your operating system is not a perfect Real-Time System, but a general purpose OS with multiple processes running at the same time and competing to be scheduled by the kernel to get its own CPU cycles.

And also, consider that, each time you execute your program or function, some of its instructions might be located at the RAM, and some might be available at the CPU L1 or L2 cache memory, and it will probably change from one execution to another. So, there are lots of variables to consider when evaluating the elapsed time for function calls using high level of precision.